# Menelaus's Theorem clarification

Tags: euclidean-geometry

> If three points, one on each side of a triangle (extended if necessary) are collinear, then the product of the ratios of division of the sides by the points is -1 if internal ratios are considered positive and external ratios are considered negative.
>
> The proof is is to show that $\dfrac{AG}{GC}\dfrac{CI}{IB}\dfrac{BH}{HA} = -1$
>
> [image]
>
> The following pairs of similiar triangles are observed.
>
> $$\triangle ADG \sim \triangle CFG$$
>   $$\triangle BEI \sim \triangle CFI$$
>   $$\triangle BEH \sim \triangle ADH$$
>
> And the proportional sides are
>
> $$\dfrac{AG}{GC} = \dfrac{AD}{CF}$$ 
>   $$\dfrac{CI}{IB} = -\dfrac{CF}{BE}$$
>   $$\dfrac{BH}{HA} = \dfrac{BE}{AD}$$
>
> Then $\dfrac{AG}{GC}\dfrac{CI}{IB}\dfrac{BH}{HA} =  \dfrac{AD}{CF} -\dfrac{CF}{BE} \dfrac{BE}{AD} = -1 $

Sorry for the long introduction post, but the proof you see above is Menelaus's theorem shown in my book. I have some concerns over the conventions used.

In particular, I am extremely confused by the equality $$\dfrac{AG}{GC} = \dfrac{AD}{CF}$$

How did they decide to use GC instead of CG or CF instead of FC for that matter? I know that the original equality $\dfrac{AG}{GC}\dfrac{CI}{IB}\dfrac{BH}{HA} = -1$ was derived from going around the triangle counterclockwise.

I even tried to mirror and flip the triangles, that is.

So I should get $\dfrac{AG}{CG} = \dfrac{AD}{CF} = \dfrac{GD}{GF}$

What is wrong with my reasoning?

**EDIT**: After asking my professor about this, he said it was poor convention and that the book was swapping the magnitudes and the "vector" segments without being explicit. Problem solved...

[image]